# Zend Routing Not Working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

I am trying to set up my zend route using the routes.ini and bootstrap but for some reason it is not able to route as expected. My routes.ini and bootstrap.php are as follows.

routes.ini

```
[production]
routes.guestbook.route = "/guestbook"
routes.guestbook.defaults.controller = guestbook
routes.guestbook.defaults.action = index
```

bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initRoutes() 
{

// Get Front Controller Instance

$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

// Get Router
$router = $front->getRouter();

$router->addConfig(new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/routes.ini', 'production'), 'routes');

}
```

Comment: I want my domain.com/guestbook to invoke my guestbook controller and index action, but currently it gives me 500 error.

Comment: FYI, your bootstrap file should be `Bootstrap.php` (capital "B")

Answer (score 2):

After I've read your comment, I can assert that you can delete those statements (config and bootstrap) because what you want to achieve is the normal behavior of the zend framework default router unless you're using modules.

Thanks to [FloydThreepwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406181/floydthreepwood) who remeber me to write this detail.

Comment: @FloydThreepwood You're right but I assumed that this is not the case.

Comment: Maybe, just thought it would make your answer complete.

Comment: I am not using modules. And can you elaborate on deleting statements config and bootstrap? Thanks for you reply

Comment: @javaadgrid You can delete all the code part you posted here (3 lines of config.ini) and the whole method _initRoutes()

Comment: But why I am not able to route it successfully?

Comment: @javaadgrid I think you haven't added this new route to the Zend_Route but I'm not really sure. I like to add new routes this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870405/changing-zend-framework-default-action-based-on-the-controller/7870423#7870423

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to configure routing is by using the [`Zend_Application_Resource_Router`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.router).

Configuration goes in your `application.ini` file and that's it, no further code required.

As it appears you're using a static route (no variable path components), try this in your `application.ini` file

```
resources.router.routes.guestbook.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
resources.router.routes.guestbook.route = "guestbook"
resources.router.routes.guestbook.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.guestbook.defaults.controller = "guestbook"
resources.router.routes.guestbook.defaults.action = "index"
```

Remove the `_initRoutes()` method from your `Bootstrap` class.

---

Also, this is just an aside but when using other resources such as the front controller in a bootstrap `_init*` method, you **must** ensure they've been properly bootstrapped. To do so, retrieve them like this

```
protected function _initSomething()
{
    // make sure resource is bootstrapped
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');

    // retrieve resource
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
}
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap.dependency-tracking