# changing zend framework default action based on the controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

So I know that you can set a custom default action in Zend Framework in the `application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "something"
```

But what if I want this default action to be contingent on the controller? So controller `A`'s default action will be `B`, controller `C`'s default action will be `D`, etc how do I configure the controllers to take these default action parameters? What piece of code is needed and where should I place them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add in your Bootstrap.php something like this:

```
   protected function _initRoutes()
   {
      $Router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

      $Route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                      '/controller1',
                      array(
                          'action' => 'customaction1'
                      )
      );
      $Router->addRoute('c1', $Route);

      $Route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                      '/controller2',
                      array(
                          'action' => 'customaction2'
                      )
      );
      $Router->addRoute('c2', $Route);

      [...]
   }
```

Comment: hmm should I place this in the controller?

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot No. As I said, you should add to the Boostrap.

Comment: Your init function doesn't show the access to `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite`, `$Router` is just `null` here. Also, creating routes and injecting them is more appropriate during dispatch, for example in a frontController plugin during `routeStartup`. Otherwise you need to bootstrap the frontController first and grab the router from there.

Comment: @JurianSluiman Wow, a downvote just for a little mistake in which, anyway, it's clear the logic. Thank you.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa it is more than that: #1 the $Router was not initialized #2 You're depending on the bootstrap of the frontcontroller first (which is now still the case and a *very* bad practice) #3 you don't bootstrap the front controller first (see also #2) and #4 working with routes like this should really be done in a frontcontroller plugin if you can't simply use the routes resource in the application.ini.

Comment: @JurianSluiman So let me understand. You want to add 4 lines per route in your .ini where you have to put more extralines for set the default values, the translator that could dinamically change and where you have to put extra-extra-lines to do validation on the route element and this should be a good way?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa nice catch in downvoting me because I give you serious arguments why this solution isn't the good approach. Imho you have two good options (see my post). You make several errors in the answer and make a common mistake to forget the frontcontroller resource plugin to bootstrap. You don't downvote because you "don't like" the answer but rather because the answer has several mistakes or points the user who started the question in the wrong direction.

Comment: @JurianSluiman I explained my reason. The code in the .ini would be a big mess if you're runnig a serious project with several routes. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to handling lots of routes could be to have the controller decide what he wants to do:

```
public function indexAction() {
  $this->_forward('mydefault');
}

public function mydefaultAction() {
  $this->view->message = 'I get called on /controller/index';
}
```

My GUESS is, that this approach is faster than adding dozens of custom routes. But that's just a guess, nothing tested here.

Comment: Not faster because your application will be dispatched twice.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up! Now i know i should change that :)

Answer (score -2):

By default you can only say in general what the default action for a controller is. If you want to dispatch a certain controller and action under a specific URI, you can do this by using [routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html).

There is a default route which you probably use in your application right now. You can add additional routes from the application.ini or otherwise create a frontController plugin to inject routes into the router. The former is much easier, the latter gives you more abilities, for example to load routes based on entries in the database.

The routes in application.ini are good explained in the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.router) of ZF. It comes down to these four lines per route:

```
resources.router.routes.route_id.route = "/login"
resources.router.routes.route_id.defaults.module = "user"
resources.router.routes.route_id.defaults.controller = "login"
resources.router.routes.route_id.defaults.action = "index"
```

Here it is possible to specify the default action by `defaults.action`. For parameters in routes, the section about the [Zend_Controller_Router_Route type](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard) explains it pretty well.

The other option is a frontController plugin. This class can hook into different parts of the process and this system is very powerful if used correctly. It is probably not required for your question, but you might want to have a look at the manual where there is a [page about plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) and a section how to [load these plugins in your application.ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.frontcontroller).

Comment: I really don't like this solution. This kind of method is going to do the .ini a mess of lines that, for a lot of routes, will be less managable.

Comment: Please don't take this personal and downvote me just because you "don't like" my answer. It is a working and acceptable answer and I give two options to choose from. The routes in the application.ini are for most simple applications a really good solution. If you don't prefer the routes in the application.ini, I give a suggestion to use a frontcontroller plugin. Those two options cover any type of use case, are commonly used by most ZF developers and will not cause any trouble if you want to refactor your code at a later moment.

Comment: As I said, nothing personal. I take a look at your solution and in my opinion this will do a big mess in the long run with several routes.